# How do I fetch text inside ui li tags in jsoup?

Tags: android, jsoup

I need to fetch the names inside the "tag-editor-tag" tag.

The Output Should be:

Name1

Name2

Name3

Name4

Name5

How can I Fetch these names alone using Jsoup in Android?

```
<ul class="tag-editor">
   <li style="width:1px">&nbsp;</li>
   <li>
      <div class="tag-editor-spacer">&nbsp;,</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-tag">Name1</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="tag-editor-spacer">&nbsp;,</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-tag">Name2</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="tag-editor-spacer">&nbsp;,</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-tag">Name3</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="tag-editor-spacer">&nbsp;,</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-tag">Name4</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div>
   </li>
   <li>
      <div class="tag-editor-spacer">&nbsp;,</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-tag">Name5</div>
      <div class="tag-editor-delete"><i></i></div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I have tried this:

```
        Elements tag_elements = doc.select("div ul.tag-editor");
        tag_elements = tag_elements.select("li");
        for(Element elem : tag_elements){
            System.out.println(elem.select("div div").text());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should find all the `div` elements with `class=tag-editor-tag` and then extract their `text`:

```
Elements tag_elements = doc.select("div.tag-editor-tag");        
    for(Element elem : tag_elements){
        System.out.println(elem.text());
    }
```

The output is:

> Name1
>     Name2
>   Name3
>   Name4
>   Name5